# KeyboardAvoidingView offset issue

Tags: react-native

I'm using KeyboardAvoidingView in react-native app, its working fine in OS 15+ < 16.0 versions but in 16+ versions its breaking and verticalOffset is not working , do anyone has any idea about this?
Thank you